# What was the need for Lorentz transformation in pre-relativity period?

Tags: physics, light

Why was it necessary for the velocity of light to be invariant between different inertial frames and hence what was the need for Lorentz transformation when it was believed that velocity of light was constant with respect to aether. Was Lorentz transformation build in order to explain the null result of Michelson-Morley experiment?

Comment: See [History of Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#History).